# Retrieve piece of words from string using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$mystring = '[5][1][0]One[4][0][0]Two[8][1][1]Three';
```

How to get these:

```
$prefix1 = '[5][1][0]';

$prefix2 = '[4][0][0]';

$prefix3 = '[8][1][1]';

$newString = 'One Two Three';
```

Comment: How dynamic is this string? Are there always and only the words `One`, `Two`, `Three`?

Comment: Not only these words...dynamic words and length of words unknown

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two examples of using `Regex` to extract the desired results. This could be optimized into one expression. But it should be a starting point for you:

*To get:* `"One Two Three"`

```
preg_match_all("/\]([a-z]*)/i", $a, $m);
print implode(' ', array_filter($m[1])) . "\n";
```

*To get:* `"[5][1][0]"`, `"[4][0][0]"` and `"[8][1][1]"`

```
preg_match_all("/(\[[0-9\[\]]*)[a-z]/i", $a, $m);
foreach($m[1] as $v) {
    print $v . "\n";    
}
```

### Further reading

- [Regular Expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)
- [Pattern Modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
- [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: Oh My God...lees than one hour you solved my problem. Thanks very much insertusernamehere